# NHibernate mapping by code equivalent for <database-object>

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an NHibernate mapping that makes use of a <database-object> element that makes use of a definition class. The mapping looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="Foo" assembly="Foo">
  <database-object>
    <definition class="Foo.AuxilliaryData,Foo"/>
  </database-object>    
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This works fine, but I would like to use mapping by code as per NHibernate >=3.2. Is there a way to do this?

(Out of interest, my reason for wanting to convert this is so that R# "Find usages" will work for the `AuxilliaryData` class. At the moment R# (and any other code inspection tool) thinks that this class is unused).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add it when generating the Configuration object

```
config.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new Foo.AuxilliaryData());
```

Comment: Thanks Firo. It's obvious now that you point it out. Thanks very much for your help.